# What could be causing for ASP.NET MVC form to not properly submit/deserialize?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This looks like it should be working, yet the form submits with model not properly deserialized.  Using latest ASP.NET MVC from nuget. .NET 4.5

A very standard user-registration View/Controller.

View:

```
@model Alertera.Portal.Web.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };

        user.SetEmail(model.Email);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _bus.Publish(new UserCreated(user));

            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

All of the posts are coming in with model being empty or forgery token not present (depends if I enable or disable verficiation).  I'm simply stumped and don't know where to look.

** EDIT **

If I disable antiforgery, ModelState is invalid, all of the fields in the model are empty and error messages state that fields are required.

I'm using Autofac with MVC extensions and Model binder is registered like so:

```
    builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
```

Autofac is working in general, as controller is instantiated properly and is injected with propery dependencies.

Edit 2:
Created a custom binder by inheriting from the DefaultModelBinder, per suggestion, so that I could see the transformation.  It looks like the bindingContenxt's model is null

[image]

The view model itself is here:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "User name")]
  public string UserName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Password")]
  public string Password { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
  [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
  public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Email { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: CHeck the `ModelState` error collection.

Comment: Are there any ModelState errors?  Does the model get bound correctly if you physically remove the AntiForgeryToken from the form and the action?  Have you specified a custom model binder, or just the default auto-magic implementation?

Comment: Thx for the questions, responses have been edited into the thread

Comment: Does your RegisterViewModel has getters and setters defined?

Comment: What types of transformations are the model binder performing (can you share this code also)?  Also, I assume you're using `DataAnnotations` attributes to mark fields as required.  Since this appears to be working (based on the ModelState errors), the disconnect would appear to be with the model binder itself.  If it's custom, that code would help, if it's not, try creating a custom one for the RegisterViewModel so you can step through the binding and compare your form fields to your model names.

Comment: I'm not really doing any transformations and was using the default binder.  I created a custom binder (inherited from the Default one) and got to the breakpoint where I could inspect the data being transformed.  It looks like the model object and FormValueProvider of the bindingContentx are empty.

Comment: If you haven't yet, double check in browser's network debug tab that the values are indeeed being submitted in the POST request with the expected names.

Comment: Thanks, I checked.. Form data is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full day of trubleshooting, updating all of the nuget packages, making sure that web.config's are all tight and contain proper assembly redirects, routes are neat, and even repair of .NET framework and other time consuming and irrelevant activities, I've finally figured this out:

A few weeks prior, we've introduced an Autofac binding that would capture serialized HttpContext along with other relevant data for when the logging framework would need it. (Imagine being able to log request information alongside a full exception stack inside a business object without polluting business logic with session/logging data.)
Unfortunately, as a part of the binding creation, the HttpContext was being serialized by Json.net and not at the time of the logging of the event, but at the time of the binding.

Apparently, when Json.net seralizes HttpContext, it actually reads the streams inside it for the first time, causing the submitted form data to be read, so that when Controller is instantiated and data for it is posted, the streams have already been read and Request.Form colection is empty.

Simple fix to only create a delegate to serialize HttpContext appears to have fixed the issue